# Python process management

Tags: python, process, ps

Is there any way python is natively, or through some code available online (preferably under the GPL), capable of doing process management. The goal is similar to the functionality of ps, but preferably in arrays, lists, and/or dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PSI

Answer (score 2):

This one is cross-platform:
http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Answer (score 0):

There is something out there called [ProcessManager](http://www.humanized.com/ProcessManager/), but I have not used it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in a module, you might also have a look at the `/proc` filesystem, procfs.